# How to make column download or not dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a store website that we want to make available to mobile users.  Completely redesigning this site is not an option.  The store has a left and right sidebar that is purely informational and is not necessary to purchase items.  I have been given the task of "hiding" the sidebars for mobile users.  I can easily use CSS to say `#rightSidebar {display:none;}` but it is graphic heavy and still will download to a user's cell phone extremely slowly.

The store is in ASP.NET C# and the sidebars are ConLibs and I know I can put logic in there to say "if mobile don't do this" but my boss doesn't want that extensive amount of change to the store.  (I know. :( )  Is there anything else that I'm overlooking that would let me "hide" the content without it downloading first?  I'm no pro in .NET so thought I should ask you folks if there's something I am missing or haven't learned yet to do this.  I feel the best method is to modify the ConLib but unfortunately that's not an option for me at this time.

Thanks!

Comment: Without modifying the application and what happens server-side, hiding the content is really all you can do.

Comment: I can make mods but because of the constraints put on me I can't hack the ConLib.  I'm afraid the boss has made the rules such that, as you say, there is nothing else I can do.  Thanks

Comment: Are the [graphic-heavy] images in the CSS or `<img />` tags (or something else)?

Comment: I don't know why all people think that it is possible to make an efficient mobile layout without touching the legacy code. He has to understand that if he wants quality he must invest in it (from his point of view I consider developer costs as investment)

Comment: I agree Sven. Deverill's boss needs a reality slap.

Comment: Why do you think mobile users aren't interested in information but desktop users are?  Sounds like a poor design overall.

Comment: pete: They are graphics heavy images and are in `<img />` tags.

Comment: cimmanon: This is a full-store being chiseled down to mobile devices.  I can change dimensions and such with CSS but we don't have real estate or bandwidth for our mobile users to have to see banner ads for package deals or the weather in the city they will be touring in.  I agree about the design but the reality of it is I have a full-blown store they want me to make work on a phone and I'm trying to avoid having to create an entire ecosystem of a 2nd store including databases, etc.

Comment: Sven, you are absolutely right but he sees a severely understaffed department with hard deadlines and bosses asking him to do a ton more and doesn't understand that a big investment now can pay off for years to come in a much greater amount.  It comes down to "Good, fast cheap - pick any 2."

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  I'm closing this as it is not productive to leave open for others to stumble on.  Or can I? hmmm.